# How to use Sed to Replace Wildcard with Space

Tags: sed

So here is my input:

```
list toblock '123
456'
```

How will I use sed to replace `list toblock` with wildcard with space for this code didn't work

```
sed -i "s/list toblock '*.'/list maclist 'sampletoreplace'/g"
```

Comment: Not clear, please provide more details which thing you want to substitute. Also wrap your samples in `{}` button called CODE TAGS, let us know once done.

Comment: list toblock '1st to block(newline)2nd to block' i wanted to replace all list toblock '' contents with list toblock 'sampletoreplace'

Comment: Please edit your post with sample of expected output in CODE TAGS and let us know  then, comments are not meant to post samples.

Comment: @apokalypto  Is `list toblock 'sampletoreplace' ` you want, or `list maclist 'sampletoreplace'`? Since in your own code the substitute target was the latter one. Aso you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54730002/edit) your question to show your desired output. the edit button is below the question, between `share` and `flag`.

Comment: Update your question to show your current 2 input lines in context surrounded by other relevant lines from your input file, and add the expected output given that input. I suspect the problem you're really asking about is how to deal with the string within single quotes spanning multiple lines but your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

It's `.*` you needed, not `*.` (`.` means any character, `*` mean repeat any times including 0 time).
Also `sed` is a line-stream editor, so by default the match will be limited within the current line.

If you want to match multiple lines, the simplest way is to use `-z` switch (GNU sed):

```
echo "list toblock '123
456'"|sed -z "s/list toblock '.*'/list maclist 'sampletoreplace'/g"
list maclist 'sampletoreplace'
```

But since `sed` usually works with RegEx greedy mode, and not support `.*?`(stop greedy mode), so you might want to change to:

```
sed -z "s/list toblock '[^']*'/list maclist 'sampletoreplace'/g"
```

In which `[^']` means `any character that is not a '`.